# Flutter: How to get PageView to stop at a certain point (use as a drawer)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

I'm using a PageView for my Flutter App, but I just realized that I don't know how to stop scrolling at a certain point like a drawer, but flutter drawer simply covers the page underneath, so here is the ideal scenario I want:

[image: Ideal pageview]

And you cannot scroll anymore after reached that certain point, ***the same effect as the Profile Page of Instagram :)***

And this is a normal drawer:

[image: Normal drawer]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stop the pages in `PageView` without snapping to the next or previous page automaically, you can set the parameter `pageSnapping` to `false`.

Below is the example.

```dart
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    return PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      pageSnapping:false,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Actually, I don't wanna just stoppage snapping, but you cannot scroll anymore after reached a certain point :)